# unicode string literals using double-quotes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unicode-literals

in SQL Server we denote unicode string literals thus:

```
declare @s nvarchar(max)
select @s = N'test'
```

however, we can also use double quotes... so we should be able to do this:

```
set quoted_identifier off
declare @s nvarchar(max)
select @s = N"test"
```

but there I've gone wrong:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near 'test'.

what is the correct form?

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, you can use the double-quote to specify the name of a column in a SELECT statement, in the same way use can use square brackets [].

Compare

```
select 1 as "value x"
select 1 as [value x]
```

both resulting in a column named `value x`.

For string literals, only `''` and `N''` can be used.

**Update** after comment from Nikola

The [MSDN page on T-SQL constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) mentions the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER/double-quote/single-quote behavior only for "character string constants", but the section "Unicode strings" only refers to the `N''` notation.

Comment: Not quite, OP uses [set quoted_identifier off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to alter this behaviour. The question is why are we not allowed to specify unicode constant using double quotes.

Comment: Oh, thank you @Nikola. Right answer to the wrong question, then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double-quotes to delimit Unicode character strings in T-SQL.

So what?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

You can still embed single-quotes within a Unicode string by doubling them up.

```
SELECT N'This isn''t a problem'
```

Comment: The problem is that we might have a large amount of text with many single quotes in it and it is much easier to double-quote the whole thing. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: It *is* an answer to the question.  The desired syntax is just incorrect and double-quotes can't be used with Unicode literals.  And, there is a workaround.  If it's difficult to double-up the single-quotes manually, then use the Find/Replace function of SSMS (or whatever editor) and replace each ' with two of them within the selected text.